# Are tensorflow op not vectorized?

Tags: tensorflow

Can somebody tell me what is meant when people say that tensorflow's ops are vectorized?
As far as I could check, it seems that running most ops on tensors results in code that is nor vectorized nor using SIMD, am I correct?

For instance, some ops like tf.math.sign, tf.math.great will have their implementation point to [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b22875dac971db391e7a7789f3a532f6be0c8f0f/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_ops.h#L723), which is then calling Eigen for each op. The eigen implementation itself is not doing any fancy things either, for instance for "greater than" operation it will simply do `a > b` and not vectorized not SIMD computations.

So, am I missing something or are the operations not vectorized?